# why Date object returns wrong day?

Tags: java

I am doing this..

```
String dateString = "12 Nov 2011 12:00"
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(date.getDay());
```

this prints out day as 3 ? why is this happening ? how can I print the correct day?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`Date.getDay()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay())?

Comment: no I haven't yet, but I have been using it for quite some time and always worked fine for me

Comment: I suggest you read the docs; the answer is right there.

Comment: umm rofl, I would highly recommend checking out @OliCharlesworth's link. Also, Date is pretty much deprecated. I would use the Calendar.get() function to get any part of a date object. It is much more accurate and safe.

Comment: +1 to Oli. Nothing more to say.

Comment: I get correctly 6, do you gave the complete code for this case. Can you print out date.toString()? Maybe it contains more hints. @Oli Charlesworth: following the documentation, the output should be 6, that is also what I get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the documentation it is worth learning by that.

date.getDay() prints the day of the week. It should display 6 as that is a saturday, not sure how you got 3 as the result.

Answer (score 3):

**date.getDay()** returns the day of the week **as a zero-indexed numeric**. In this case it should be Saturday (6).

Your result of Wednesday (3) suggests you are using a variation of the provided code and perhaps forgotten that the month is zero-indexed. e.g.

```
Date date = new Date(2011, 11, 12, 24, 0, 0); // month is now December, and time ticks over to Wednesday 13th
System.out.println(date.getDay()); // this would produce 3
```

<s>I believe you want **date.getDate()**.</s>

If you are looking for a String representation of the day, take a look at this example:

http://www.java-examples.com/formatting-day-week-using-simpledateformat

Even better, check out the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library, it is much more intuitive than the classes provided in the Java SDK. A future version of Java may even adopt a new date framework similar to Joda-Time ([JSR-310](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/02/jsr-310))

Comment: but wouldn't getDate return the whole date, I just want the Day ?

Comment: @HellBoy: Seriously, just read the docs!  It's not like they're complex.

Comment: 2011-11-12 is not Wednesday, it is Saturday.

Comment: Mnementh: of course it is Saturday, I should have checked that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed should print 6, as this date is a Saturday. On my computer that happens. without further information I cannot deduce more. Is this the complete code you execute? You could print the value of date.toString(), that would possibly give some more information.